# How Does SQL Server Know What Precision To Display Real Data Types To?

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

I am trying to replicate tables from a remote SQL 2000 database into my local SQL 2012 instance.

As a quick way of checking for values which have changed, I am using the "UNION ALL...GROUP BY" technique found on [Simple Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/on-comparing-tables-in-sql-server/) (scroll about half-way down).

Unfortunately, the remote data types are set as REAL and as this is an approximate data type this is not very reliable as it finds differences where I don't want it to (even though those differences exist computationally).

I have tried using CONVERT to change the values to a NUMERIC (exact) data type. However, different columns have different numbers of decimal places and finding a one size fits all solution is proving difficult.

One thing I noticed is that if I run the following query (TimeID is an INT and Value1 is a REAL):

```
SELECT [TimeID], [Value1], CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,10), [Value1]) AS [CONV19,10], CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,3), [Value1]) AS [CONV19,3], CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,4), [Value1]) AS [CONV19,4]
FROM   [DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]
WHERE  [TimeID] = 12345
```

I get the following results:

```
[TimeID]     [Value1]     [CONV19,10]          [CONV19,3]        [CONV19,4]
12345        1126.089     1126.0885009766      1126.089          1126.0885
```

Note that SQL Server Management Studio displays Value1 to 3 decimal places when in its native format (i.e. without me converting it).

So my question is: how does SSMS know that it should be displayed to 3 decimal places? How does it know that 1126.0885 is not the actual number stored, but instead is 1126.089?

Ideally I'd like to understand it's algorithm so I can replicate it to convert my data to the correct number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question but will give you a starting point to answer it yourself?

First read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx

Notably, "The behavior of float and real follows the IEEE 754 specification on approximate numeric data types."

Now read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

So now you should know how float/ real numbers are stored and why they are "approximate" numbers.

As for how SSMS "knows" how many decimals are in a real/ float I don't really know, but it is going to be something to do with the IEEE 754 specification?

A simple script to demonstrate this is:

```
DECLARE @MyNumber FLOAT(24) = 1.2345;
SELECT @MyNumber, CONVERT(NUMERIC(19, 4), @MyNumber), CONVERT(NUMERIC(19, 10), @MyNumber), CONVERT(NUMERIC(19, 14), @MyNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard. I've already read both those links previously and am reasonably comfortable with the fact that REAL data types are approximate (hopefully my example conversions show this). In an ideal world I'd change the remote databases to NUMERIC but sadly this is provided by a third-party and unchangeable. It seems to me that SSMS knows what to round to, perhaps I'll need to try my own investigations to determine how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *know* if this is the case, but I suspect that SSMS is using .NET numeric string formatting.

I was having a similar situation, I simply wanted to `SELECT` into a `VARCHAR` the exact same thing that SSMS was displaying in the query results grid.

In the end I got what I wanted with the [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-format-with-numeric-types) function, using the [General format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#the-general-g-format-specifier).

For example:

```
DECLARE @Floats TABLE([FloatColumn] FLOAT);
INSERT INTO @Floats
VALUES
(123.4567),
(1.23E-7),
(PI());

SELECT
Number = f.FloatColumn,
Text = FORMAT(f.FloatColumn, 'G'),
IncorrectText = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), f.FloatColumn)
FROM @Floats f;
```

I have to give the disclaimer that I don't know if this will work as desired in all cases, but it worked for everything I needed it to.

I'm sure this is very useful after six years.